# MVC 3 with Razor best practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am looking for best practices for using Razor with MVC 3.  Now what I am hoping for is some type of article, not just a list of your professed best practices, but if you have any feel free to post them.

Why is this SO worthy?  It seems hard to find info on how to best use Razor with MVC views.  I know about the typical MVC best practices, I am looking for Razor specific ones.  Those who use Razor know that its more than a token replacer.  I want to know more about how you setup the site templates using Razor.

Like I said, I am looking for a good resource on the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you ever heard of [Nerddinner.com](http://www.nerddinner.com)? that website has been created with ASP.NET MVC an it is open source on [codeplex](http://codeplex.com).

Here is the release that has razor and MVC3 version of it;

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/55257

You could download the source code and play with it.

**Edit :**

Also have a look at below blog posts;

- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Implicit and Explicit code nuggets with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)
- [Deployment of ASP.Net MVC 3 RC 2 Application on a Shared Hosting Environment Without Begging The Hosting Company](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/39)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)
- [Razor Releated posts on Phil Haacked's Blog](http://haacked.com/search.aspx?q=razor)

Comment: why is that? it is a good open source project and there are number of versions of it in view of view engine.

Comment: NerdDinner is meant as a beginners guide. Why wouldn't it be good for reference? It's not the Holy Grail and it's by far not all best practices, but if you're looking for a place to start NerdDinner is a great option!

Comment: I disagree. you can learn lots of hardcore stuff on nerddiner project as well.

Comment: @Sergi you are also right I think. it's good place to start. I think reading good code is the better practice than reading tutorials. Nerddiner is one of them. It refers both low and high level.

Comment: @jfar - Maybe not reference *code*, but definitely *good for reference*! Again, a great place to start if you're just starting

Comment: Well, of the links provided only the 2 on Scott Gu's site are worth reading because all the others are very outdated.  Nerd dinner needs some serious updating and must have been using RC or earlier bits.  The problem is if you learn from code thats obsolete you will confuse your self and others.  I think nerddinner is a great source of learning when its up to date, but when its not its just subject to frustration.  I am not new to MVC3 nor Razor, I was looking for a best practices, which seems to not exist.

Comment: Per some experts like Mark Seeman (Dependency Injection in .NET book) and Ayende http://ayende.com/blog   specifically here : http://ayende.com/blog/4092/reviewing-nerddinner   They have noted in blogs and books that there are some bad practices, bad names, anti-patterns and code smells etc..  I now look at Nerddinner with skepticism.  The Wrox MVC 3 book endorsed the Service Locator which is a KNOWN anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Razor syntax is not all that you are looking for, you want the best patterns and practices with using MVC 3 as well.  It is a shame there are Zero books out on MVC3, only web references with vary from small to large degree.  At this point you must use stackoverflow and constantly use google and set a date range to search past month or so.  Also, setup a google "alert" on mvc 3 razor etc..

I find that pluralsight examples, nerddinner, Silk (MileageStats), MvcMusicStore, ProDinner, and several others to be "useful" yet not one is (or can be) the best practices in every area.   Everyone tries the "happy path" but many of the example veer from this. Many examples are doing various IOC containers. Some use Unity others Structuremap, others Ninject.  Depending on skill level and existing knowledge, it can be overwhelming.

Personally I'm on a new project with vs 2010 / mvc3 with Oracle 9... Thus MOST of the examples are not terribly helpful as the database integration with EntityFramework use datacontext / IQueryable is great and all, but with Oracle EF in beta, and sprocs not even working with Oracle 9 with EF (per trying , and email responses from Oracle trainers etc..)  I end up having to go old school and retrofit ADO.NET and convert to List ... and use IEnumerable.  Thus many of the things stubbed out for easy use in the models/controllers/views in the demo projects are half in vain for me with my environment with Oracle.

Comment: There are many books out on MVC3, a quick search on Amazon will net you many.

Comment: @EdDeGagne   I wrote this in June 2011, BEFORE the books came out.  Thanks though

Comment: I bought my MVC book way before that date and there were quite a few available in MVC2 and a few with MVC3 prior to your post. :)

Comment: I was working feverishly on MVC 3 project in May 2011 and the MVC 3 books I pre-ordered on Amazon were ALL postponed due to extra features and tooling updates done in April.  Yes, I already had 4 MVC 2 books,  Apress, Wrox, Manning and a Test Drive one with a Race car on the cover.  I verified this with Gmail account of mine and Amazon, and a few friends.  So no, it was not true.  First book was MVC 3 from Apress to ship to me on  6/27/11 (but I didn't see the email, no book arrived at the time of this writing, then  Professional ASP.NET MVC 3.0   $27.36  (Wrox book) Amazon Shipped on 8/2/11

Comment: I prefer razor syntax, new current features and best practices and thus I RARELY still open my 4 books written on MVC version 2 .  I use the MVC 3 books from Wrox and Apress for current references.   Once again, these books were NOT available this is not simply an opinion, this is a fact as I was teaching classes once a week on MVC and developers in JUNE 2011 were saying "I Cannot believe there are no books on MVC 3 yet"  End of Story.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well... I use MVC 2 and work and MVC 3 at home and I really haven't found too many differences in terms of best practices for the Razor syntax.  I generally just read ScottGu's or Phil Haack's blogs if I want to read about ways to use the features of Razor.  Not sure if that helps you any but I am drawing a blank.

Comment: I have read their blogs and generally read then within days of a posting.  Most of their Razor stuff is old.  Most of the example Razor code doesnt even work.  Razor is so new in MVC that I find its hard just to find good examples.  Write a good blog post with some meat, post it here, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: @CrazyDart, If you are comfortable with MVC2 I'm not sure how you need a crash course in Razor. Think of it as a souped up version of the aspx engine.

Comment: @CrazyDart scoot hanselman always says that 'less you think about razor, more your confertable with it' just type @ and write your c# code. the rest will flow. belive me !

Comment: Somehow I dont think putting that in as the answer for my research task for team coding standards is going to make anyone very happy.  That may work in the contractor world, but when you have to live with the garbage code you write its perhaps better to give it more thought.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below link for example with good presentation.
http://dotnetautor.de/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/32ee537b2c00_E16A/MVC3.pdf